# Cancel Paypal Sandbox Recurring Payment

Tags: wordpress, paypal, sandbox, recurring-billing

I have found many answers to this question but they are all either outdated or explain how to do it in a Paypal live account and not the sandbox.

If there isnt a way yet can someone explain to me how I can simulate a canceled recurring payment. I have tried to delete the user sandbox account but that is giving me an error. I need a way to cancel this recurring payment as if I were a user trying to stop the payment because if the user stops payment I would like to cancel their access to my site. I believe most of this has been coded for me in a plugin I am using for wordpress but without being able to delete the user account or canceling the recurring payment within the paypal sandbox I have no way of testing this.

Comment: Awesome a down vote and no explanation!

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @HoangTrinh I created an answer for this question and accepted it. Give that a try and let me know if you need something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the sandbox user you created in your developer account login at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com

Once logged in go to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/myaccount/settings/payments

Then click the link "Manage automatic payments"